# Laravel: How to use 'd' JS function variable within JS blade loop?

Tags: javascript, laravel, foreach

Hi my question is very confusing but I hope you can understand it with my explanation :). I have been doing this for hours and I cannot use the d variable in my loop function. In my loop function, the d variable displays but when i use it in my loop query (when i replace 166 to d.user_id), it returns me an error. How can I use the d variable in my loop function query. Below is the script. A help will be much appreciated :).

```
<script>
 /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
 locations = [
 @foreach ($data->where('user_id','=', '166')->where('type','OTHERS') as $data_array)
    @foreach ($data_array->ufees as $data_row)
        [ "{{ $data_row->code }}", "{{ $data_row->name }}" ], d.user_id
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
  ];
   return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Fee:</td>'+
            '<td>'+locations+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it like this. PHP is a server side language, meaning all PHP is processed before leaving the server. JavaScript is a client side language, meaning it all happens on the user's machine (e.g., in a web browser). You can't pass a JavaScript variable directly into PHP code because all the PHP has already been processed into HTML on the server before being sent to the web browser.

Comment: Yes, but can I atleast use this d variable in the where('user_id','=',d.user_id)? Because the d value can be displayed and I can use specific ID like 166 in my query.

Comment: You cannot use `d` which is a JavaScript variable within `where('user_id','=',d.user_id)` which is PHP.  It is not possible, ever.  See my response above.  You will need to use a different approach.

Comment: @matticustard Ah see. So what other approach you can suggest me to apply within the same script? :)

Comment: I don't know enough about your app to make specific recommendations. But a basic example would be to use AJAX (via JavaScript) to request the data from the server on demand.

Comment: Maybe you can try to make this @foreach in html and hide it, then get the data from hidden html through DOM.